# How to restart database from php in WordPress website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have an issue keep happened on my WordPress website
the database is stopped sometimes
and I have to go to the server and restart MySQL 
I tried to add code in /wp-includes/functions.php 
to restart MySQL when it is stopped but it is not working 
in function dead_db()
I have added this code

```
error_log("Mysql database is not available!", 0);
shell_exec('sh /home/restart_db.sh');
```

and the code in restart_db.sh is

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

but is not working

Comment: Better to find out why the DB is stopping in the first place and fix it than do this. Check the MySQL logs.

Comment: Check your `restart_db.sh` has execute permissions `chmod +x restart_db.sh`. Also ensure the shell script has the shebang `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Wordpress is making a big query that the server can't handle it and consume all memory in databases, so it shut down.

Comment: So fix the big query, or make it more efficient with e.g. indexes, or limit the amount of data returned (could get pages at a time), or increase mysql memory allowance?

Comment: I give the file the permission chmod +x restart_db.sh, but not working

Comment: @Jonnix I have looked in /var/log/mysql/error.log and /var/log/apache2/error.log but I didn't find logs for what happened, do you have an example for increasing mysql memory allowance